# How do I boot from USB on Ubuntu 16.10 with grub2?

Tags: partitioning, usb, gparted, 16.10

Want to shrink my windows partition and then increase the size of my Ubuntu one. I could not find a clear answer already, so I'm asking this.

Comment: Best to only use Windows to shrink NTFS partition and reboot immediately. It has to run chkdsk after any resize. And make sure fast start up is off. then you can use gparted from live installer to modify Linux partitions.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to start your computer with live USB (16.04 or any other version).  When booting, ensure you say you select to try Ubuntu (not install it).  Once it boots, load `gparted`.  From there,

1. Shrink the size of your Windows partition as desired.
2. Once the operation above is done increase the size of the Ubuntu partition.
3. Once the second operation is done, reboot from hard drive (remove USB).

This should do the trick.

Comment: According to @oldfred  's comment above, it's best to only use use Windows to shrink NFTS partitions and reboot immediately.

Comment: I kinda figured it out on my own. I went and download a partition wizard bootable iso, and ran that to downsize my windows partition. I had the most success with that, and it has a progress bar. After doing that I went into gparted and increased the size of my ubuntu partition.